# std::is_base_of for template classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is there a way to test `std::is_base_of<A, B>` when `A` is a template class?

```
template <typename X, typename Y> class A {};

template <typename X> class B : public A<X, char> {};
```

I want to statically test something like, `std::is_base_of<A, B<int>>` meaning, `B` is derived from any specialization of `A`.
(To make it more general, let's say we don't know the way `B` specializes `A`, i.e. B<X> derives from A<X, **char**>)

One way to solve would be to derived A from a (non-template) class say `C`, and then check `std::is_base_of<C, B<int>>`. But is there another way to do this?

Comment: 'A' is not a type. You cant do that, but you can do 'std::is_base_of<A<int, int>, B<int>>'

Comment: Kind of similar question I answered some time back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670375/how-to-enforce-template-parameter-class-to-derive-from-super-with-an-anonymous-t/34670684#34670684

Comment: Would `my_is_base_of<A, B<int>, char>` be a reasonable usage for you?

Comment: @TartanLlama thanks. It would be very specific to the way B specializes A though. I am looking for a more general solution, if possible.

Comment: @Arunmu thanks. I see, that could work in my setting.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename...Ts>
std::true_type is_base_of_template_impl(const C<Ts...>*);

template <template <typename...> class C>
std::false_type is_base_of_template_impl(...);

template <typename T, template <typename...> class C>
using is_base_of_template = decltype(is_base_of_template_impl<C>(std::declval<T*>()));
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dd19d21817cadf5)

but will fail with **multiple** inheritance or **private** inheritance from `A`.

With Visual Studio 2017 this will fail when the base class template has more than one template parameter, and it is unable to deduce `Ts...`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CSMZ66843)

[VS Bug Report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/318537/base-class-template-parameter-deduction-error.html)

Refactoring solves the problem for VS.

```
template < template <typename...> class base,typename derived>
struct is_base_of_template_impl
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    static constexpr std::true_type  test(const base<Ts...> *);
    static constexpr std::false_type test(...);
    using type = decltype(test(std::declval<derived*>()));
};

template < template <typename...> class base,typename derived>
using is_base_of_template = typename is_base_of_template_impl<base,derived>::type;
```

[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/QJF31861)

Comment: Huh, I had no idea that `Ts...` could be deduced in that context. Nice!

Comment: I arrived at the same solution, but this solution also __fails__ (rather than returns `false`) with single non-public inheritance from `A` :(

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks! That's pretty clever.

Comment: It seems you don't need the `typename T` in `is_base_of_template_impl`?

Comment: @davidhigh: Indeed, simplified.

Comment: Why does this fail with multiple inheritance?

Comment: @Justin: In case you inherit from both `C<int>` and `C<float>`.

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks in visual studio with more than 1 template parameter unless the second parameter is varadic... - http://rextester.com/CSMZ66843

Comment: Well, the VS bug is fixed.

Comment: It doesn't work when the template arguments contain values, anyone any ideas?

Comment: @Sprite: we unfortunately don't have syntax to handle generically between type and non-type template parameters. You have to create similar traits to handle types as `std::array`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am an engineer at Google interested in using the code you wrote here. If you are comfortable with permitting this, could you please release your snippet under a recognized open source license (https://opensource.org/licenses) by adding a comment clarifying which specific license terms apply to this snippet of code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JackHumphries: Just added in my profile the fact that original code I post on SO are under [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party here but I wanted to give a variant of the above

```
template < template <typename...> class Base,typename Derived>
struct is_base_of_template
{
    // A function which can only be called by something convertible to a Base<Ts...>*
    // We return a std::variant here as a way of "returning" a parameter pack
    template<typename... Ts> static constexpr std::variant<Ts...> is_callable( Base<Ts...>* );

    // Detector, will return type of calling is_callable, or it won't compile if that can't be done
    template <typename T> using is_callable_t = decltype( is_callable( std::declval<T*>() ) );

    // Is it possible to call is_callable which the Derived type
    static inline constexpr bool value = std::experimental::is_detected_v<is_callable_t,Derived>;

    // If it is possible to call is_callable with the Derived type what would it return, if not type is a void
    using type = std::experimental::detected_or_t<void,is_callable_t,Derived>;
};

template < template <typename...> class Base,typename Derived> 
using is_base_of_template_t = typename is_base_of_template<Base,Derived>::type;

template < template <typename...> class Base,typename Derived>
inline constexpr bool is_base_of_template_v = is_base_of_template<Base,Derived>::value;
```

This uses the proposed is_detected machanism which I think makes the intent of the test a bit clearer. However I can now get the type(s) with which the base class is instantiated at the same time which I find useful. So I can write

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct Foo { };

struct Bar : Foo<int,std::string> { };

static_assert( is_base_of_template_v<Foo,Bar> );

// The variant type contains the types with which the Foo base is instantiated 
static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::variant<int,std::string>,is_base_of_template_t<Foo,Bar>> );
```

Comment: Thanks. This is neat!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works with protected inheritance.

```
template <template <typename...> class BaseTemplate, typename Derived, typename TCheck = void>
struct test_base_template;

template <template <typename...> class BaseTemplate, typename Derived>
using is_base_template_of = typename test_base_template<BaseTemplate, Derived>::is_base;

//Derive - is a class. Let inherit from Derive, so it can cast to its protected parents
template <template <typename...> class BaseTemplate, typename Derived>
struct test_base_template<BaseTemplate, Derived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class_v<Derived>>> : Derived
{
    template<typename...T>
    static constexpr std::true_type test(BaseTemplate<T...> *);
    static constexpr std::false_type test(...);
    using is_base = decltype(test((test_base_template *) nullptr));
};

//Derive - is not a class, so it is always false_type
template <template <typename...> class BaseTemplate, typename Derived>
struct test_base_template<BaseTemplate, Derived, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_class_v<Derived>>>
{
    using is_base = std::false_type;
};
```

Surprisingly, on VS2017, it works with multiple inheritance from the same template, like C< 
int > and C< float > both. (have no idea how!)

Check the 
[Link to test code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/456d063b19204a85)

Comment: Your solution is quite good but it has a minor bug try to test static_assert(is_base_template_of<std::variant, std::variant<std::string>>::value);

Answer (score 1):

Based on Evgeny Mamontov answer I believe the proper solution is

```
template <template <typename...> class BaseTemplate, typename Derived>
struct test_base_template<BaseTemplate, Derived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class_v<Derived>>> : Derived
{
    template<typename...T>
    static constexpr std::true_type test(BaseTemplate<T...> *);
    static constexpr std::false_type test(...);
    using is_base = decltype(test((Derived *) nullptr));
};
```