# std::is_base_of for template classes (non-type template parameters)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to implement an extension for std::is_base_of for templated classes, such that if I have the following:

```
template <typename X, typename Y, int Z> class A {};

template <typename X> class B : public A<X, char, 2> {};
```

I can use something like

```
std::is_base_of_ext<A, B<int>>
```

to statically check that An is a base class from B, independently of specific template parameters and the way B specializes from A.

"*[std::is_base_of for template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672441/stdis-base-of-for-template-classes)*" provides a very nice solution to this, but it only works with type template parameters; can it also be made to work with non-type parameters?

Comment: C++11 can't do variadic mixes of types and values. You need C++17's `auto...` template parameter packs

Comment: @Caleth but you still can't have a pack containing both types and values and I think that would be needed for generic implementation of OP's is_base_of, unless they limit themselves to a specific order

Comment: No.  This is not possible in C++.  A template parameter pack cannot contain both type and non-type parameters.

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and you should first explain why do you need `is_base_of_ext`? Maybe there is some workaround if we know more (like limiting what `A` can be/have to provide).

Comment: One of possible solutions is split `A`: `template <typename X, typename Y, int Z> class A : ABase<X> {};`

Comment: You can have `has_A__as_base<B<int>>`, but you cannot have your generic function for any kind of template class.