# enable_if for templated base class (C++11) meta-programming

Tags: c++11, templates, inheritance, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have tried writing a program that behaves something like "compile-time inheritance" for example the following C++11 meta-program ...

```
// imports
#include <type_traits>

// non-templated Class class
class Base
{
    // Base class stuff
};

template <
          typename T,
          class = typename std::enable_if
            <
                std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value
            >::type
         >
class UseClass
{
    // templated UseClass class stuff
};

// UseClass class instance
UseClass<Base> myDer
```

but instead of the base class being type-agnostic, I wanted it to be more in line with something like  ...

```
// imports
#include <type_traits>

// templated Base class
template <typename T>
class Base
{
    // Base class stuff
};

template <
          typename T,
          class = typename std::enable_if
            <
                std::is_base_of<Base<T>, T>::value // Note: Base<T>
            >::type
         >
class UseClass
{
    // templated UseClass class stuff
};

UseClass<Base<int>> myDerInt // does not compile
```

Although, I have come up with an alternative/refactoring to achieve the desired behaviour for my project structure, I would still like to know why this does not work and/or how to to achieve something like this using a parallel approach as above (if possible).

I have looked at (many) other stackoverflow answers which is what helped me construct the first example, but so far I have not come up/across a solution to implementing something like the second example, maybe because it's not possible or perhaps my understanding of template programming is still underdeveloped?

I would appreciate any clarification on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`std::is_base_of` for template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672441/stdis-base-of-for-template-classes)

In your case, I believe you could do it this way:

```
// imports
#include <type_traits>

// templated Base class
template <typename T>
class Base {};

template <class U>
std::true_type IsDerivedFromBase(Base<U>*);

template <class ...>
std::false_type IsDerivedFromBase(...);

template <class T>
constexpr bool IsDerivedFromBaseV = decltype(IsDerivedFromBase(std::declval<T*>()))::value;

struct Derived : Base<int>{};

static_assert(IsDerivedFromBaseV<int> == false);
static_assert(IsDerivedFromBaseV<Base<int>> == true);
static_assert(IsDerivedFromBaseV<Derived> == true);
```

As mentioned in the linked question, it will not work with private inheritance though.