# Force template parameter class to inherit from another templated class with partially fulfilled parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, template-inheritance

So I have the following two classes:

```
template < class Cost >
class Transformation {
  public:
    virtual Cost getCost() = 0;
};

template < class TransfCl, class Cost >
class State {
    protected:
        State(){
            static_assert(
                std::is_base_of< Transformation< Cost >, TransfCl >::value,
                "TransfCl class in State must be derived from Transformation< Cost >"
            );
        }
    public:
        virtual void apply( const TransfCl& ) = 0;
};
```

But would like to, instead, be able to drop the `Cost` template parameter to `State`, because `State`'s functionality is completely independent of `Cost`.  This way, I could create non-abstract classes using a syntax similar to this:

```
class TransfImpl : public Transformation< int >{
    public: int getCost(){ return 0; }
};

class StateImpl : public State< TransfImpl >{
    public:
        StateImpl(){
            static_assert(
                std::is_base_of< Transformation, TransfImpl  >::value,
                "TransfImpl must inherit from Transformation< Cost >"
            );
        }
        void apply( const TransfImpl & ){}
};
```

I also wanted to eventually chain this to a third class, which would use the `State`-derived class as its template parameter, but wouldn't need to also have the `Transformation`-derived and `Cost`-derived classes in its template parameters to verify that its `State`-derived template parameter class is, in fact, derived from `State`

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670375/how-to-enforce-template-parameter-class-to-derive-from-super-with-an-anonymous-t

Comment: or [std::is_base_of for template classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34672753/2684539)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename...Ts>
std::true_type is_template_base_of_impl(const C<Ts...>*);

template <template <typename...> class C>
std::false_type is_template_base_of_impl(...);

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T>
using is_template_base_of = decltype(is_template_base_of_impl<C>(std::declval<T*>()));
```

You may do

```
template <class TransfCl>
class State {
protected:
    static_assert(is_template_base_of<Transformation, TransfCl>::value,
                  "TransfCl class in State must be derived from Transformation<Cost>");

    // previous code ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit your need?

```
template < class Cost >
class Transformation {
public:
    typedef Cost TransformationCost;
    virtual Cost getCost() = 0;
};

template < class TransfCl, class Cost = typename TransfCl::TransformationCost>
class State {
    static_assert(
                std::is_base_of< Transformation< Cost >, TransfCl >::value,
                "TransfCl class in State must be derived from Transformation< Cost >"
            );
protected:
    State(){}
public:
    virtual void apply( const TransfCl& ) = 0;
};

class TransfImpl : public Transformation< int >{
public:
    int getCost(){ return 0; }
};

class StateImpl : public State< TransfImpl >{
public:
   StateImpl(){}
   void apply( const TransfImpl & ){}
};
```

**ADDED**: [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bcc340024f27874)